# custom post type archive Pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type 'author' and I already make archive-author.php ,here is the problem I use wp-pagenavi plugin and I have 15 post in this custom post type I already use `$paged,'posts_per_page' =>5` in my archive-author.php and from setting>read I set max number of post to 20,but so in author archive I must have 3 pages. first and second pages work fine but the last one give 404 error, this bacome as a weird thing when I don't have this problem with default post type of wordpress.
I try to solve this problem by deleting plugin and adding manual numberic Pagination, but it show just 2 link in Pagination not even showing the third one.

here is my [website](http://royayeketab.ir/author/) link
I though maybe this problem come from my custom post type.

here is my archive-author.php codes

```
<div class="writer-crit-box col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
                        <?php
                        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                         $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author','paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' =>5); 
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="writer-link col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="writer-row1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hvr-glow">
                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 image-right">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-right writer-content">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <h4><?php the_field('auth-trans'); ?></h4>  
                                    <?php if ( get_field('writer-bio') ) { 
                                        echo '<p>'.get_field('writer-bio').'</p>';} ?>

                                    <span>...</span>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                    <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>          

                    <div class="wp-pagenavi row">
                        <div id="wp_page_numbers text-center col-sm-6 center-margin">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="active_page text-center"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $loop )); } ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>

            </div>
```

and here is my code for taxonomy

```
    <?php

function p2p2_register_author(){
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'همکاران', 'Author' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x('همکار','Author'),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'افزودن همکار', '' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'افزودن همکاران جدید' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'ویرایش همکار' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'همکار جدید' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'همه همکاران' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'جست و جو همکار' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'همکاری یافت نشد' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'همکار در زباله دان یافت نشد' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'همکار'
    );

    register_post_type(
        'Author',
        array (
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'description'   => 'ذخیره اطلاعات مربوط به همکاران',
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'menu_position'      => 2,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'author' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
        )
    );
}
        add_action('init', 'p2p2_register_author');
?>
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="writer-crit-box col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">

                <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
                    <?php
                   $posts = query_posts( 'post_type=author&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=12' );
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="writer-link col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="writer-row1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hvr-glow">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 image-right">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-right writer-content">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <h4><?php the_field('auth-trans'); ?></h4>  
                                <?php if ( get_field('writer-bio') ) { 
                                    echo '<p>'.get_field('writer-bio').'</p>';} ?>

                                <span>...</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

                <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>          

                <div class="wp-pagenavi row">
                    <div id="wp_page_numbers text-center col-sm-6 center-margin">
                        <?php pagenavi(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>

        </div>





    // Add this function to your functions.php file


/* Function that Rounds To The Nearest Value.
 Needed for the pagenavi() function */
 function round_num($num, $to_nearest) {
 /*Round fractions down (http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)*/
 return floor($num/$to_nearest)*$to_nearest;
}

/* Function that performs a Boxed Style Numbered Pagination (also called  Page Navigation).
Function is largely based on Version 2.4 of the WP-PageNavi plugin */
function pagenavi($before = '', $after = '') {
global $wpdb, $wp_query, $post;

$pagenavi_options = array();
$pagenavi_options['pages_text'] = __('Page %CURRENT_PAGE% of  %TOTAL_PAGES%:','viewr');
$pagenavi_options['current_text'] = '%PAGE_NUMBER%';
$pagenavi_options['page_text'] = '%PAGE_NUMBER%';
$pagenavi_options['first_text'] = __('First Page','viewr');
$pagenavi_options['last_text'] = __('Last Page','viewr');
$pagenavi_options['next_text'] = __('Next &raquo;','viewr');
$pagenavi_options['prev_text'] = __('&laquo; Previous','viewr');
$pagenavi_options['dotright_text'] = '...';
$pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'] = '...';
$pagenavi_options['num_pages'] = 3; //continuous block of page numbers
$pagenavi_options['always_show'] = 0;
$pagenavi_options['num_larger_page_numbers'] = 0;
$pagenavi_options['larger_page_numbers_multiple'] = 5;

//If NOT a single Post is being displayed
/*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)*/
if (!is_single()) {

    $request = $wp_query->request;
    //intval — Get the integer value of a variable
    /*http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php*/
    $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));

    //Retrieve variable in the WP_Query class.
    /*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var*/
    $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
    $numposts = $wp_query->found_posts;

    $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(is_home()){
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages - 1;
    }else{
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    }
    //echo '<script>alert("'.$max_page.'")</script>';
    //empty — Determine whether a variable is empty
    /*http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php*/
    if(empty($paged) || $paged == 0) {
        $paged = 1;
    }

    $pages_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_pages']);

    $larger_page_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_larger_page_numbers']);
    $larger_page_multiple = intval($pagenavi_options['larger_page_numbers_multiple']);
    $pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show - 1;
    $half_page_start = floor($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
    //ceil — Round fractions up (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)
    $half_page_end = ceil($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
    $start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;
    if($start_page <= 0) {
        $start_page = 1;
    }

    $end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;
    if(($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1) {
        $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
    }
    if($end_page > $max_page) {
        $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
        $end_page = $max_page;
    }
    if($start_page <= 0) {
        $start_page = 1;
    }

    $larger_per_page = $larger_page_to_show*$larger_page_multiple;
    //round_num() custom function - Rounds To The Nearest Value.
    $larger_start_page_start = (round_num($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple) - $larger_per_page;
    $larger_start_page_end = round_num($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
    $larger_end_page_start = round_num($end_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
    $larger_end_page_end = round_num($end_page, 10) + ($larger_per_page);

    if($larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple == $start_page) {
        $larger_start_page_start = $larger_start_page_start - $larger_page_multiple;
        $larger_start_page_end = $larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple;
    }
    if($larger_start_page_start <= 0) {
        $larger_start_page_start = $larger_page_multiple;
    }
    if($larger_start_page_end > $max_page) {
        $larger_start_page_end = $max_page;
    }
    if($larger_end_page_end > $max_page) {
        $larger_end_page_end = $max_page;
    }
    if($max_page > 1 || intval($pagenavi_options['always_show']) == 1) {
        /*http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php */
        /*number_format_i18n(): Converts integer number to format based on locale (wp-includes/functions.php*/
        $pages_text = str_replace("%CURRENT_PAGE%", number_format_i18n($paged), $pagenavi_options['pages_text']);
        $pages_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pages_text);
        echo $before.'<div class="pagenavi">'."\n";

        if(!empty($pages_text)) {
            echo '<span class="pages">'.$pages_text.'</span>';
        }
        //Displays a link to the previous post which exists in chronological order from the current post.
        /*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link*/
        echo '<span class="pnlink">';
        previous_posts_link($pagenavi_options['prev_text']);
        echo '</span>';

        if ($start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page) {
            $first_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['first_text']);
            //esc_url(): Encodes < > & " ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote, single quote).
            /*http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation*/
            //get_pagenum_link():(wp-includes/link-template.php)-Retrieve get links for page numbers.
            echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link()).'" class="first" title="'.$first_page_text.'">1</a>';
            if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'])) {
                echo '<span class="expand">'.$pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'].'</span>';
            }
        }

        if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_start_page_start > 0 && $larger_start_page_end <= $max_page) {
            for($i = $larger_start_page_start; $i < $larger_start_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
                $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="single_page p1" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
            }
        }

        for($i = $start_page; $i  <= $end_page; $i++) {
            if($i == $paged) {
                $current_page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['current_text']);
                echo '<span class="current">'.$current_page_text.'</span>';
            } else {
                $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="single_page p2" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
            }
        }

        if ($end_page < $max_page) {
            if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotright_text'])) {
                echo '<span class="expand">'.$pagenavi_options['dotright_text'].'</span>';
            }
            $last_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['last_text']);
            echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($max_page)).'" class="last" title="'.$last_page_text.'">'.$max_page.'</a>';
        }
        echo '<span class="pnlink">';
        next_posts_link($pagenavi_options['next_text'], $max_page);
        echo '</span>';

        if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_end_page_start < $max_page) {
            for($i = $larger_end_page_start; $i <= $larger_end_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
                $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="single_page p3" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
            }
        }
        echo '</div>'.$after."\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The Post number default call from admin default post amount, if you want to set custom post amount, you can set $posts_per_page = your amount in pagenavi() function.

Comment: it doesn't even show the page navigation, just show all posts. I don't get exactly what you mean?

Comment: $posts = query_posts( 'post_type=author&orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=5' ); add this before your start loop

Answer (score 0):

Use of `get_next_posts_link()` and `get_previous_posts_link()` shall break your error and get cool to your page error.

```
<div class="writer-crit-box col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
<div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-12">
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Author','paged' => $paged,'posts_per_page' =>5); 
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="writer-link col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="writer-row1 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 hvr-glow">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 image-right">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail',array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 pull-right writer-content">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <h4><?php the_field('auth-trans'); ?></h4>  
                    <?php if ( get_field('writer-bio') ) { 
                        echo '<p>'.get_field('writer-bio').'</p>';} ?>
                    <span>...</span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>          
    <div class="wp-pagenavi row">
        <div id="wp_page_numbers text-center col-sm-6 center-margin">
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next Page', $loop->max_num_pages ); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo get_previous_posts_link( 'Previous Page' ); ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>              
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this and share me if you face any hinderance

Comment: HI, Try adding this and will solve your problem. Replace `'rewrite'=> array( 'slug' => 'author' ),` with `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'author', 'with_front' => true ),`

Comment: Try the above lines and let me know still you face any issue mam.